# What was the dynamite for? Was it a red herring?

Tags: plot-explanation, rushmore

In Wes Anderson's [Rushmore](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0128445/), we see Max ordering dynamite from a store prior to staging his play. He asks the order to be made out to *Ready Demolition, Tucson, Arizona*. Yes, said play involved a war and there were lots of effects. But what was the necessity for the dynamite?

Were the explosives a red herring for the audience? I personally expected him to blow up the newly constructed aquarium (especially after his conversation with Herman about how much money he is prepared to lose).

Answer (score 3):

I believe the dynamite was meant for the play.

Rather than his line being a red herring, it's a direct reference to the movie [Heat](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113277/).

When Max buys the dynamite and says, "Could you make the order out to Ready Demolition, Tucson, Arizona", he is using the exact same line used by Val Kilmer in the first scene of Heat.

Comment: Val Kilmer's line, as spoken, is "And, uh, make it out to Tax Demolition, Tuscon" -- different company name and more terse -- but you're correct in the essentials.